# SSIS Multiple Unknow Column Updates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I wonder if anyone has come across a similar situation before that could point me in the right direction..? I'll add that it's a bit frustrating as someone has replaced the NULL value with a text string containing the word 'NULL' - which I need to remove.

I have 6 quite large tables, over 250+ columns and in excess of 1 million records in each and I need to update the columns where the word NULL appears in a row and replace it with a proper NULL value - the problem is that I have no idea in which column this appears.

As a start, I've got some code that will list every column with a count of the values and anything that looks to have a lower count than expected, I'll run a SQL query to ascertain if the column contains the string 'NULL' and using the following code, replace it with NULL.

```
declare @tablename sysname
declare @ColName nvarchar(500)
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
declare @sqlUpdate nvarchar(1000)
declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar(1000)

set @tablename = N'Table_Name'  
Set @ColName = N'Column_Name'
set @ParmDefinition = N'@ColName nvarchar OUTPUT';

set @sql= 'Select ' + @ColName + ', Count(' + @ColName + ') from ' + @tablename + ' group by ' + @ColName + ''
Set @sqlUpdate = 'Update ' + @tablename + ' SET ' + @ColName + ' = NULL WHERE '+ @ColName + ' = ''NULL'''

print @sql
print @sqlUpdate 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @ParmDefinition, @ColName=@ColName OUTPUT;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlUpdate, @ParmDefinition, @ColName=@ColName OUTPUT;
```

What I'm trying to with SSIS is to iterate through each column,

```
Select Column_Name from Table_Name where Column_Name = 'NULL'
```

run the appropriate query, and perform the update.

So far I can extract the column names from **Information.Schema** and get a record count from the appropriate table, but when it comes to running the actual UPDATE statement **(as above, sqlUpdate)** - there doesn't seem to be a component that's happy with the dynamic phrasing of the query.

I'm using a **Conditional Split** to determine where to go if there are records (which may be incorrect) and I've tried **OLE DB Command** for the update.

In short, I'm wondering whether SSIS is the best tool for this job or whether I'm looking in the wrong place!

I'm using SSIS 2005, which may well have limitations that I'm not yet aware of!

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principle is basically sound, but I would leave SSIS out, and do it with SSMS directly against the SQL Server and build the looping logic there, probably with a cursor.

I'm not sure whether you need to check the count of potential values first - you might just as well apply the update and accept that sometimes it will update no rows - the filtering will then not be duplicated.

Something like

```
declare columns cursor local read_only for
select 
    c.TABLE_CATALOG,
    c.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    c.TABLE_NAME,
    c.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
        on c.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG
        and c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
        and c.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
where c.DATA_TYPE like '%varchar%'  

open columns    
declare @catalog varchar(100), @schema varchar(100), @table varchar(100), @column varchar(100)

fetch from columns into @catalog, @schema, @table, @column

while @@FETCH_STATUS= 0
begin
     -- construct update here and execute it.       
    select @catalog, @schema, @table, @column
    fetch next from columns into @catalog, @schema, @table, @column
end

close columns
deallocate columns
```

You might also consider applying all the updates to the table in one hit, removing the filter and using `nullif` dependent on the density of the bad data.

eg:

```
 update table
 set
    col1 = nullif(col1, 'null'),
    col2 = nullif(col2, 'null'),
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah, checking the count just doubles the amount of table and/or index scans that need to be done, since the update typically will do a full scan anyway...

Answer (score 1):

SSIS won't be the best option for you. Conceptually, you are performing updates, lots of updates. SSIS can do *really* fast inserts. Updates, are fired off on a row by agonizing row basis.

In a SQL based approach, you'd be firing off 1000 update statements to fix everything. In an SSIS based scenario, using a data flow with OLE DB Command, you're looking at 1000 * 1000000.

I would skip the cursor myself. It is an acceptable time to use a cursor but if your tables are as littered with 'NULL' as it sounds, just assume you're updating every row and fix all the fields in a given record instead of coming back to the same row for each thing needing fixed.

Comment: I was only suggesting the cursor to build the list of tables/columns, not to do the update itself.

Comment: I had a feeling that SSIS wasn't going to work, but I had to prove it to myself and have found some useful guides in the process.

At the moment I'm content enough just to update the rows as I am in the above code snippet and I'll find a way of looping through the columns in SSMS. 

I have a similar cursor statement that located the columns, I used this as the basis of the SSIS column criteria, so I'll try and work it into a different solution.